# form will not process after correcting validation errors.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where I am parsing the contents of a field and then setting two other fields in the controller.

In other words, if employee_raw_name is ["Christopher Mendla"] I strip off the [""] and split the name into first and last.

That works fine unless validation fails, then I get

```
NoMethodError in ObservationsController#create
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/employee_observations

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/observations_controller.rb:243:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"JGV9M89AoaTAmcjhKCQUw75S01lee6MJsHWniPssGt+uFucY3YXRzhyWdBCxKTZ6zwSPz/qvfCHhsWeDRDNr8w==",
 "observation"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2016",
 "date(2i)"=>"6",
 "date(3i)"=>"9",
 "status"=>"Sent to employee for acknowledgement",
 "performance"=>"Positive",
 "disciplinary_notice"=>"",
 "department_id"=>"",
 "observation"=>"asdasd",
 "comments"=>"asdasd",
 "discussed_with_employee"=>"0",
 "date_discussed"=>"2016-06-10"},
 "commit"=>"Create Observation"}
```

Line 243 is in the create def below `employee_name  = employee_name[2...-2]`

```
    def create
        @observation = Observation.new(observation_params)


    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # the following will take the employee_raw name and parse it into a first and last name. Then it will set up a user
    # for that name if a user does not already exist.

   '
          employee_name = @observation.employee_raw             # Employee_raw is from the listing from LDAP
          employee_name  = employee_name[2...-2]                # strip off the "[  and ]"
          employee_name = employee_name.split(' ')              # split into first and last names based on a space.
          # TODO - Account for initials and names such as Van, Von, La etc.
          employee_first_name = employee_name[0]                # grab the first name and populate the field
          employee_last_name= employee_name[1]                  # grab the last name and populate the field.
          $temp3 = '|' + employee_first_name + '|'
```

I put an <%= action_name %> on the form so I could see if there is a difference. When I first load the form, the action is 'new'. If there is a validation error, then the action is 'create'. I suspect that is the root of the problem but I'm not sure how to work around it. I tried putting that block in 'if action_name != 'create'` but that didn't work.

Comment: @observation.employee_raw is evaluating to nil.  `create` has to be able to recover in the case that your form submission fails.  I would start by ensuring the object you create is valid before doing work on it.  Typically that would be done with `if @observation.save`..., but since you need to do other work, you may check `valid?` first, then do work on the `@observation`

Comment: How employee_raw is expected to be created for @observation object? It's not passed as part of observation_params based on the Parameters output you quote. Do you have anything in the model that creates this field?

Comment: What's your form for observation code?